# How do you use pvkconverter.exe - not working for me?

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

I tried to following [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2914662/how-to-use-pfx-formatted-certificates-in-sql-server) to convert a .pfx file to the .cer and .pvk file pair.

When I run this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\PVKConverter\PVKConverter.exe" -i TDE_Cert.pfx -o Out_Cert -d mydecryptpassw
```

It *does not* produce any file, nor does it give any error. Could someone help?

I actually had the above command wrapped inside a `.bat` file.  This `.bat` file and the `.pfx` are both in the same directory.  I uninstalled the x86 install and re-installed the x64 version thinking I should be running the x64 version on my Win7 Prof SP1 machine.  Same issue.  When I deliberately misspelled the password or even omit it, no errors.  Nothing!  I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this to work.  A couple of issues.

1. I had to shell out to the command prompt "as administrator"
2. had to install "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012".

Here's the weird part.  If I run "pvkconverter.exe' with the -d option, it gives me an error saying it requires a decryption password.  If omit the "-d" option, it generates the "PVK/DER certificate pairs" which i can see my .cer and .pvk files now.  I got my files now but not sure if they are legit.

I guess the ONLY definitive way to find out if the `.cer` and `.pvk` files are valid is to run them on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the documentation example and your supplied example code, you're not supplying an encryption password (-e switch).

Without this, the tool cannot encrypt the new private key file with a password, which SQL requires to decrypt it later when creating the certificate. I'm guessing the tool simply doesn't produce the files in this instance. Try adding a password to encrypt the files and see if that helps.